# How can I access something from scope inside deeply nested ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat which can actually nest an unlimited number on ng-repeats inside it based on what the user does. Basically they can create more items which then allows you to create more items inside that item if they want.

Now the problem is that inside every item I need to be able to access `$scope.pageId` so I can do an ng-if to only display certain things depending on the pageId.

At the moment `$parent.pageId` will work but only for the first item. As of course the parent of the next nested item will be the first item and not the scope.page

Is there a way I can pass through the `scope.pageId` into each nested ng-repeat of Item as they move further away from scope in terms of their `$parent`?

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: @PhilippSander Mistails answer code is a fine example although I need to be able to access 'value' from any repeat. It needs to be dynamic as I'm not sure how many repeats the user will create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to a variable of the scope everywhere in your controller, including in nested `ng-repeat`:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Mistalis';
  $scope.complexArray = [
    [
      [
        [{
          'value': 123456
        }]
      ]
    ]
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="i in complexArray">
      <div ng-repeat="j in i">
        <div ng-repeat="k in j">
          <div ng-repeat="l in k">
            {{l.value}}
            <br/>My name is {{name}}!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a problem with this though. I want to access 'value' from any of the repeats. The way you have done is that you know what repeat you want to access it from and then nested it in the correct place in scope.complaxArray. I need to be able to access it from any of the repeats and there could be anywhere from 1 repeat to 20 repeats.

Answer (score 0):

The usual practice is to define a service keeping the data that you want to access and use a controller on the element displaying it. The controller will query the service and make the data accessible to the view.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .factory('SectionNamePageIdService', [
    function() {
      return {
        setPageId: function() { ... },
        getPageId: function() { ... )
      };
    }
  ]);

angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('NestedItems', ['SectionNamePageIdService',
    function('SectionNamePageIdService') {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true, 
        template: '<div ng-repeat="item in nestedItems"></div>',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.pageId = SectionNamePageIdService.getPageId();
        }]
      };
    }
  ]);
```

The example assumes you have a `nestedItems` object in the parent scope. You may want to define a separate `NestedItem` directive to take care of how each item is displayed, as well. I don't know how you intend to pass the data down the nested items, so this is just a basic example. You may want to define service(s) for the data as well.

However, looking at your comments, I really doubt such nesting is good by design. From UX perspective, deep nesting (20 levels!) seems unwieldy to me. So before trying to find a technical solution, it may be good to revise the problem on a conceptual level first.